# JQuery - Each com multiplos arrays

Tags: jquery

Preciso fazer um each com vários items, exemplo:

Como posso fazer isso ?
O "item" já gera o resultado do array "data.id_site" mas preciso de um novo array junto, o "item2" que gera o resultado do array "data.name".

Seria algo como:

```
$.each(data.id_site, data.name, function(i, item, item2) {
    $(".lado").append("<div id='site-" + item + "'>" + item2 + "</div>");
});
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a pergunta? Podes dar um exemplo do que tem o `data` e do resultado que esperas obter?

Comment: alterei a pergunta, preciso de um each com mais de 1 array, é isso!

Comment: Queres então algo como `$(".lado").append("<div id='site-" + item + "'>" + name + "</div>");` é isso?

Comment: Sim!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que ambos `data.` e `data.name` têm o mesmo numero de elementos, podes iterar um deles como estás a fazer e usar o `indice` para ir buscar o que queres ao outro array. Assim:

```
$.each(data.id_site, function(i, item) {
    $(".lado").append("<div id='site-" + item + "'>" + data.name[i] + "</div>");
});
```

Porém para não estar a chamar sempre o `.append()` é melhor fazer assim:

```
var divs = data.id_site.map(function(id, i){
    return "<div id='site-" + id+ "'>" + data.name[i] + "</div>"
}).join('');
$(".lado").append(divs);
```

Comment: era isso mesmo, vlw!